# Can't create users in rails when using authlogic because of cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, authlogic

So, I have a standard rails 3 app with authlogic. If I'm not in the browser (in the console or in the test environment), I can't create user models.

For example:

I have this code either in a rspec test or in my console:

```
user = User.create(...user attributes...)
```

And I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `cookies' for main:Object
```

I've looked all over the internet and can't figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

So, I looked around some more and found in the documentation to do this:

```
include Authlogic::TestCase
```

but then I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant Authlogic::TestCase
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same exact problem. Where in your application did you put the following line:

```
Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)
```

I ran into this error when I placed the line in either the `environment.rb` file or within a file within my initializer folder.

I eliminated the problem when I placed the line in my `ApplicationController` instead.

Comment: I didn't find that line in my code base. I show my solution here: https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/354